# Problems in Adding AIMS WFS Layers in Openlayers 3.10

Tags: openlayers, wfs, autodesk

I'm working with AIMS(Autodesk Infrasture Map Studio) and openlayers 3, I have a WFS layers in AIMS Server that i want to display using OL3. it doesn't show any errors, the map appears but the layers does not show. it works with wms ol3, but not wfs.
I'm using latest version of openlayers 3.10.1 and examples of wfs layers http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.1/examples/vector-wfs.html

Please can anyone help me to fix that? This is my code :

```
 var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
   format: new ol.format.WFS({
     featureNS: "http://fdo.osgeo.org/schemas/feature/ns224280581",
     featureType: "BRGYBOUNDARY"
   }),
   url: function(extent,resolution, projection) {
   return 'http://192.168.7.7/mapserver2014/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=ns224280581:BRGYBOUNDARY&maxFeatures=1000&outputFormat=GML3&srsname=EPSG:4326&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
 },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
  maxZoom: 19
  }))
 });
var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
 source: vectorSource,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
   stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
   color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
   width: 2
  })
    })
 });

  var raster = new ol.layer.Tile({
  source: new ol.source.OSM
 });

  var map = new ol.Map({
   layers: [raster, vector],
   target: document.getElementById('map'),
    view: new ol.View({
     center: ol.proj.transform([120.604169, 15.480071], 'EPSG:4326','EPSG:3857'),         
maxZoom: 19,
zoom: 12
  })
});
```

AIMS WFS Layers
http://192.168.7.7/mapserver2014/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi?service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=ns224280581:BRGYBOUNDARY&maxFeatures=1000&outputFormat=GML3&srsname=EPSG:4326

Answer (score 1):

The url you provide doesnt work. Try to use the following code for your vector layer. It will show if the url fails to load.

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
loader: function (extent) {
    //place here any actions on start loading layer
    document.getElementById('laodingcont').innerHTML = "<font color='orange'>start loading.....</font>";
    $.ajax('http://192.168.7.7/mapserver2014/mapagent/mapagent.fcgi', {
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            service: 'WFS',
            version: '1.1.0',
            request: 'GetFeature',
            typename: 'ns224280581:BRGYBOUNDARY',
            srsname: 'EPSG:4326',
            bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
        }
    }).done(loadFeatures) //success function here (loadFeatures)
        .fail(function () {
        //place here any actions on fail loading layer
        document.getElementById('laodingcont').innerHTML = "<font color='red'>error loading vector layer.</font>";
    });
},
strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox
});
//get back the success responce and manipulate
function loadFeatures(response) {
    formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS(),
    vectorSource.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
    document.getElementById('laodingcont').innerHTML = "<font color='green'>finish loading vector layer.</font>";
}
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot the URL is not accessible through the public by the IIS server, but I have the payload of WFS request or GML of the URL.  I tested my code on other vector layers and its working fine the layers appear in the map. this is the WFS request or GML file of the URL, can you check whats wrong in that file? https://08182560605081092855.googlegroups.com/attach/327da45d130d6/Boundary.gml.txt?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrHDeKwcfsPDBjjy3f5QjaH7D-t7SL0Ad24dNjxTwIT5SRPIpE9gygLMg80wm7m4FhRQRL3P5a9SUtl9HKmV-9Z1jX4bVa4JfjV0btpdH_l9JykT_AI

Comment: here is the URL GML File https://08182560605081092855.googlegroups.com/attach/327da45d130d6/Boundary.gml.txt?part=0.1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrHDeKwcfsPDBjjy3f5QjaH7D-t7SL0Ad24dNjxTwIT5SRPIpE9gygLMg80wm7m4FhRQRL3P5a9SUtl9HKmV-9Z1jX4bVa4JfjV0btpdH_l9JykT_AI